# Datavalidation/Dropdown based on a filtered list with 2 conditions

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010, dropdown

I'm looking for a way to create a dropdown based on a list and two filter conditions.

I've created a file as demonstration, it contains a table with name-, gender-, and age-values which acts as database and is supposed to be expanded.

Then there is a user table where you can enter the gender and the age.
After that I would like to get a dropdown based on those two conditions.

In my example that would mean if I choose "Male" and "50" the dropdown should show Henrik and Bernd as options.

[image: Example]

Comment: This can be done with just formula, but requires a bunch of named ranges and helper columns. A VBA approach might be more straight forward.

Comment: [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nb84p2wX-c) gives a fairly elegent solution to a very similar problem using the `INDIRECT` function. This could definitely be adapted for your purposes.